# Simultaneously Parallelizing and Vectorizing Code in R

Tags: r, data.table

I am working with the R programming language.

I have this dataset that contains consecutive exam results from students over a period of time - I am trying to use this dataset to calculate the conditional probability of a student failing the next exam, given that the student failed the previous exam. The data looks something like this:

```
library(data.table)

  id = sample.int(10000, 100000, replace = TRUE)
res = c(1,0)
results = sample(res, 100000, replace = TRUE)
date_exam_taken = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 100000, replace = TRUE)


my_data = data.frame(id, results, date_exam_taken)
my_data <- my_data[order(my_data$id, my_data$date_exam_taken),]

my_data$general_id = 1:nrow(my_data)
my_data$exam_number = ave(my_data$general_id, my_data$id, FUN = seq_along)
my_data$general_id = NULL
```

**I have been spending some time learning how to "vectorize and parallelize" a function in R that will be able to calculate these conditional probabilities** .

My initial code was a FOR LOOP - I was told that "vectorizing" your code allows R to simultaneously perform operations on multiple elements compared to a FOR LOOP which only allows R to perform operations on a single element, thus allowing for an increase in efficiency and a decrease in time/speed. On the other hand, I was told that "parallelizing" can potentially make your code run faster as it allows your computer to allocate more processing power through allocating the task at hand to different "cores" within your computer.

Thus, I tried to exploit both of these principles (vectorizing and parallelizing) and incorporate them both into my code. Furthermore, I was told about the advantages of using the "data.table" library in R and converted my data frame into a "data.table" object for another potential gain in performance.

Here is my attempt:

```
# First, load the "doParallel" library
library(doParallel)
library(data.table)

# Set up a cluster with 4 cores
cl = makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)

my_data = as.data.table(my_data)

# Now, you can use the `foreach` function with the `%dopar%` operator to parallelize the computation
my_vector = foreach(i = unique(my_data$id), .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
    {tryCatch({

  # Inside the function, everything works the same as before
  #setDT(my_data)
  start_i = my_data[my_data$id == i,]
  
  pairs_i =  data.table(first = head(start_i$results, -1), second = tail(start_i$results, -1))
  frame_i =  data.table(table(pairs_i))
  frame_i$i = i
  #print(frame_i)
  return(frame_i)

}
, error = function(e){})
    }}

# Don't forget to stop the cluster when you're done
stopCluster(cl)
```

From here, I would then perform a series of JOINS on the results and calculate the different conditional probabilities (pass given pass, pass given fail, fail given fail, fail given pass), and place these results in a 2x2 contingency table.

The code seems to run - but I am interested in knowing if I have done this correctly and what could have been done differently.

**Can someone please tell me if I have done this correctly?**

Thanks!

Comment: This question is hard to answer because it's not clear (to me at least) what you need to do, what result you're expecting, or what constitutes success. vectorization, parallelization, and using data.table functions can all be used to improve performance for certain situations. But we don't have enough information to know what level of performance is adequate for your needs or what step in your process is the main bottleneck. Getting high performance in R often involves rethinking the structure of the solution, but there's not much here for us to go on.

Comment: Why are you loading data.table but then only using data.frames?  Why are you parallelizing trivial computations?  Parallelizing is only helpful when you're doing processor intensive work otherwise the overhead of making new processes is more time consuming that the underlying work.  Vectorizing in R means you do operations on a whole vector instead of a for loop.  As an example if you have `a=c(1,2,3)` and `b=c(2,3,4)` you can just do `a+b` to get `c(3,5,7)`.  You don't have to (and shouldn't) do for(i in 1:length(a)) a[i]+b[i] as you'd need to do in other languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular problem is not well suited for parallelization. The expense of setting up the cluster exceeds any benefit, especially when a vectorized solution is straightforward.

By sorting the table by `id` then `date_exam_taken`, we can get the previous exam result and then drop rows where breaks in `id` occur.

`data.table` then allows us to efficiently aggregate by the four combinations of results in order to form the contingency table.

```
m <- matrix(
  setorder(
    dt[
      # get the results from the previous row (first row is NA)
      ,res0 := shift(results)
    ][
      # keep only rows that have the same id as the previous row
      id == shift(id)
    ][
      # group by the four cases (pass-pass, pass-fail, etc.) and count the occurrences of each
      , .N, c("res0", "results")
      # sort descending by the current exam, then descending by the previous exam
    ], -results, -res0
    # put the results into a 2x2 matrix
  )$N, 2, 2, 0, list(c("pass0", "fail0"), c("pass1", "fail1"))
)
m # 2x2 contingency table by count
#>       pass1 fail1
#> pass0 22527 22460
#> fail0 22491 22524
m/rowSums(m) # by proportion pass/fail given the results of the previous exam
#>           pass1     fail1
#> pass0 0.5007447 0.4992553
#> fail0 0.4996335 0.5003665
```

This will be very fast. However, if performance is an overriding concern (as opposed to, e.g., readability), we can squeeze a little more out by using `tabulate` instead of `data.table` grouping operations. Put the two solutions in functions and test their performance with `microbenchmark`.

```
f1 <- function(dt) {
  if (!identical(key(dt), c("id", "date_exam_taken"))) setkey(dt, id, date_exam_taken)
  m <- matrix(
    setorder(
      dt[
        ,res0 := shift(results)
      ][
        id == shift(id)
      ][
        , .N, c("res0", "results")
      ], -results, -res0
    )$N, 2, 2, 0, list(c("pass0", "fail0"), c("pass1", "fail1"))
  )
  m/rowSums(m)
}

f2 <- function(dt) {
  if (!identical(key(dt), c("id", "date_exam_taken"))) setkey(dt, id, date_exam_taken)
  m <- matrix(
    with(
      dt,
      tabulate((shift(id) == id)*(4L - 2L*results - shift(results)), 4L)
    ), 2, 2, 0, list(c("pass0", "fail0"), c("pass1", "fail1"))
  )
  m/rowSums(m)
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1(dt),
                               f2(dt),
                               check = "identical")
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>    expr    min     lq     mean median      uq     max neval
#>  f1(dt) 3.0650 3.9351 4.931590 4.1148 4.63785 12.1386   100
#>  f2(dt) 1.5193 1.7114 1.933132 1.7479 1.77500  7.8051   100
```

Data:

```
library(data.table)
(seed <- sample(.Machine$integer.max, 1))
#> [1] 1849007255
set.seed(seed)

dt <- data.table(
  id = sample.int(10000, 100000, replace = TRUE),
  results = sample(0:1, 100000, replace = TRUE),
  date_exam_taken = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 100000, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Comment: thank you so much! is there a way to adapt this for multiple sequences (e.g. fail, fail, pass)?

Comment: Yes, although I think a good algorithm in a single-pass `for` loop would give the best performance. It would be a good case for `Rcpp`. This question was understandably closed, so that problem would best be addressed in a new question.

Comment: Thank you so much! If you have time, can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74806562/correctly-using-clustereval-in-r ? Did i do this correctly?

Comment: I added a comment to the linked question. BTW, I was able to work through the relatively simple Rcpp solution for a look-back greater than 1. It runs even faster than either of my solutions here, even for full tables of proportions conditioned on relatively long looks-back (10+), e.g., pass-10, fail-9, pass-8, ... pass-2, pass-1, pass.